# Linking html files in Node.js

Tags: node.js

**Server.js**

.....
.....

app.configure(function() {

```
// map .renderFile to ".html" files
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// make ".html" the default
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');

......
```

}

**register.html**

```
<form class="form-signup" action="/admin/signup" method="post">
....
....
</form>
```

**login.html**

```
<a class="link-width" href="views/register.html">Register</a>
```

but clicking the link doesn't work, though i have register.html in public\views\register.html

the below code is working, but i have hardcoded the domain and port which is a bad 
practice(in future these values might change)

```
<a class="link-width" href="http://localhost:9090/admin/register">Register</a>
```

server side

```
res.render("login", {message : ""});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a handler for this url?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass site url from app.locals like this WHERE you can pull siteurl from config file:

```
app.locals({
site_url : cfg.site_url
});
```

then in view file you can do <%= site_url %>

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure middle-ware to serve static content.

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/public' ));
```